# Connect to Docker container via ipv6 (macvlan)

Tags: ubuntu, docker

My goal is to make my container ipv6 accessible. When I try to execute this command to create a macvlan which should make ipv6 connectivity possible (or so I was told) I get this weird error (it actually works without the ipv6 flag but that's not what I want...). I've searched for a solution for hours and can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated. IPv6 Connectivity from the host system is given.
Host: ubuntu 20.04 server

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.1 --subnet=2a02:120b:ffff:ffff::/64 --gateway=2a02:120b:ffff:ffff::1 -o parent=eth0 --ipv6 macvlan
```

```
Error response from daemon: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

my daemon.json file:

```
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "2a02:120b:ffff:ffff::/64",
    "log-level":        "error",
    "storage-driver":   "overlay2"
}
```

Other than the default networks I only have a network for one other container that doesn't use ipv6 so I'd be surprised if that was a problem.